# In Joomla, how do you create a page with the same alias as a deleted one?

Tags: url, joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0

Working with Joomla (3.8.8) for the first time and I'm trying to create a landing page with the URL of (/start). I created this already as a test to see how it worked and later deleted it, but now when I try to create a page with the same alias I get this message: https://screencast.com/t/uR1ZIBg9.

However, there are no items in the trash, unpublished or anything. When I try to go to the /start page it just redirects me to the home page with "/component/users/?view=login&Itemid=101" appended to the end.

What's even weirder is the page still shows up on module assignments, etc.(https://screencast.com/t/i3lsjw5X) like it ever got deleted. Is there a way to fix this through the Joomla dashboard somewhere? Or do I have to delete some specific rows out of its database?

Comment: You should only have to trash it and then empty the trash.  Or just rename the old one.  Given your errors, I would go into phpmyadmin #__content table and search by alias, then delete old line.

Comment: @YellowWebMonkey Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I ended up only need to delete the the old alias in the #_menu table. Once I did that it seemed to fix everything.